# Visual Studio Warnings with CosmosDB nuget package install

Tags: xamarin.forms, azure-cosmosdb

I am doing a Xamarin Forms project and installed CosmosDB nu get package but I am getting the following warnings that I am unable to get rid of

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Warning NU1701  Package 'Microsoft.Azure.CosmosDB.Table 1.1.0' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework 'UAP,Version=v10.0.16299'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.             
Warning NU1701  Package 'Microsoft.Azure.CosmosDB.Table 1.1.0' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETStandard,Version=v2.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.   NWMPosNG    C:\Users\MattDouhan\source\repos\NWMPosNG\NWMPosNG\NWMPosNG\NWMPosNG.csproj
```

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft.Azure.CosmosDB.Table currently only targets .NETFramework 4.5, but .NET Standard support will be out soon.

Comment: Can I switch my project to framework? Or have I ended up in a catch 22 situation ? I need cosmosdb, azure mobile client and local storage